# uncomment an xml element, add attribute and print to output xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I've a scenario, when I need to uncomment the SSL configuration from server.xml (tomcat) and also need to add a couple of attributes in it. I succeeded adding two attributes when there is SSL configuration already available but my template doesn't work for the just uncommented part. Any idea?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="new2.xsl"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>


  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->

    <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <!--NEED TO UNCOMMENT AND ADD ATTRIBUTES IN THE FOLLOWING ELEMENT--> 

    <!--<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" /> -->


    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">


      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

The xslt is following which uncomments the part and if the part is already uncommented, adds the two attributes in it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="Copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="insertConnector">
    <xsl:call-template name="Copy" />
  </xsl:template>
<!--If the SSL configuration doesn't exist but availabe in comments, uncomment it-->
  <xsl:template match="comment()[not(../Connector[@scheme = 'https']) and
                                 contains(., 'Connector') and
                                 (contains(., 'scheme=https') or
                                  contains(., scheme='https'))]">

    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/> <!--This line uncomments the comment-->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match = "Connector[@scheme = 'https']" name="AddAttributes">
    <Connector keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </Connector>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please guide me how can I add the attributes in commented part or add the attributes in the element right after uncommenting it. Above XSLT is only uncommenting the SSL configuration part. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this, at least not in XSLT 1.0. The uncommenting process simply outputs the comment's content as unescaped text, but doesn't recognize it as XML data. Would it be possible for you to do a two-pass approach, where you run the XML once through the XSLT to uncomment that portion, and another time to add the comments?

Comment: Hi, I tried it as you said because I need to create an Ant file which would transform the xml so in Ant file, I processed the file two times which produced the required result. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding my comment here as an answer because this is the approach you eventually went with:

I don't think there's a way to do this, at least not in XSLT 1.0. The uncommenting process simply outputs the comment's content as unescaped text, but doesn't recognize it as XML data. Would it be possible for you to do a two-pass approach, where you run the XML once through the XSLT to uncomment that portion, and another time to add the comments?

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the content of the comment to an XML parser either by writing your own extension function, or by calling an extension such as saxon:parse() provided by your XSLT processor, which is standardised as parse-xml() in XSLT 3.0. Alternatively use a two phase pipeline with the help of disable-output-escaping as suggested by @JLRiche.